# django translate model choices

Tags: django, django-models

I need translate a choices for a field on the model.
I have something like this:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    TYPES = (
        (1, _("Option one")),
        (2, _("Option two"))
        (3, _("Option three"))
    )
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=TYPES)
```

Before this I have a script on the login view:

```
request.session['django_language'] = request.POST.get("language")
```

So, the problem is when django calls the TYPES on MyModel, because the request.session['django_language'] doesn't exist.

Comment: I want to clarify:  you have written a view that uses the request.POST.get("language") value, and you are not using django forms to manage the input?  You are trying to assign to 'django_language' in the session, and it is failing?  Please show the whole view function, and paste the actual error you get.

Comment: I will try to be clear.

I execute this line:


`request.session['django_language'] = request.POST.get("language")`


When the user start session, django changes between english and spanish languages. with all templetes I use `{% trans "Hello" %}` are translated. But pyhon "compile" all models before this. So, the class properties don't make translations in real time. the only method is changing the language option in the configuration file, but server needed to be restarted.


All model's examples with choices shown, uses it the way I'm doing it.

Answer (score 23):

In models.py, you need to

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

ugettext_lazy will return a callable rather than the translated string.  When the callable is evaluated later, it will return the translated string.  It will be late enough that it will get the right language for the view/template processing.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#lazy-translations.

This next part was not your question, but:  in django you should use forms to process the user input, rather than accessing it directly from request.POST.get.  That's a whole other topic, but I could not let it go unaddressed in this answer, for fear someone else might use that method.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example for translating values that you save in your db.

```
#models.py

from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_noop


CATEGORY_CHOICE = (
  ("choice one", gettext_noop("choice one")) # gettext_noop will mark the string to be translated when you later do "python3 manage.py makemessages"
  ("choice two", gettext_noop("choice two"))
)

class Foo(models.Model)
  category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=50)
```

Just do `python3 manage.py makemessages` to generate the locale django.po files, enter the translations. And then do, `python3 manage.py compilemessages` to compile your locale files.

Now, at the time of returning this field from your views or api, just make sure to do this:

```
#views.py

from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

def get_category():
  foo = Foo.objects.get(id=1)
  return _(foo.category)
```

Comment: The only answer that helped me because it contains example for views!

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm late to the party but I've just resolved a similar problem. There's a very good solution in the django documentation.

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
class Student(models.Model):
    class YearInSchool(models.TextChoices):
        FRESHMAN = 'FR', _('Freshman')
        SOPHOMORE = 'SO', _('Sophomore')
        JUNIOR = 'JR', _('Junior')
        SENIOR = 'SR', _('Senior')
        GRADUATE = 'GR', _('Graduate')

    year_in_school = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=YearInSchool.choices, default=YearInSchool.FRESHMAN,)
```

SEE [LINK](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/)

Alternatively.

1. Deploy enums (enums.py) within the app folder like so:

.

```
from enum import Enum, unique
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
@unique class SomeChoice(Enum):
  first = _('First Option')
  second = _('Second Option')
```

Obviously, you'll then import the enum into your model & use as needed.
e.g

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True, choices=[(s.name, s.value) for s in SomeChoice])
```

At this stage, I'm assuming you've already written your locale files, so you have your .po files already set up.

```
#Append your translation content within .po | or via rosetta app

django-admin makemessages -all

django-admin compilemessages
```

Click the alternative language link

Answer (score -5):

**models.py**

```
CATEGORIES = (  
    ('LAB', 'labor'),
    ('CAR', 'cars'),
    ('TRU', 'trucks'),
    ('WRI', 'writing'),
)


class PostAd(models.Model):  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    gist = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=CATEGORIES)
```

**forms.py**

```
CATEGORIES = (  
    ('LAB', 'labor'),
    ('CAR', 'cars'),
    ('TRU', 'trucks'),
    ('WRI', 'writing'),
)

category = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CATEGORIES, required=True)
```

**category.html**

```
<!-- category -->
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.category.errors }}
    <label for="id_category">Category</label>
    {{ form.category }}
</div>
<!-- location -->
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This answer does not appear to solve the question, since it does not contain any translations.